# what is the meaning when a property's type is a protocol in swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I come across code like this:

```
protocol A
{
//some properties and methods
}

class B
{
 var property1: A
}
```

what exactly does the property1 signify? 
Does it mean that property must conform to protocol A ? Or is it like other properties of class type?
Is there any specific reason why my property must be of a protocol type and not a class?
Please try to explain with an example because I'm really confused with this.

Comment: Please read [Protocols as Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID275) in the Language Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property1 is anything that conforms to protocol `A`. So this could either be another class, a struct, etc. Say you have a protocol `Vegetable` and a class named `Market`. You'll want to sell multiple types of `Vegetable`, however, you want to make sure that the vegetables are for sale. You can do this with protocols.

```
protocol Vegetable {
  var isForSale: Bool { get }
}

// Now let's create some vegetables
class Carrot: Vegetable {
  let isForSale = true
}

class Spinach: Vegetable {
  let isForSale = false
}

// This is our market.
class Market {
  let vegetables: [Vegetable] = [Carrot(), Spinach()]

  // Now we can check if the vegetables are for sale, because we know for sure that they conform to Vegetable so must implement this variable.
  var forSale: [Vegetable] = {
    vegetables.filter { $0.isForSale } // This will return [Spinach()]
  }
}
```